# Checking if a certain dictionary is in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a .json file containing the following:

```
"[{'x':{'xx':'192.111.1.11'}},{'y':{'yx':'192.111.1.12'}}]"
```

I tried to use:

```
if x in somelist:
  return something
```

But this never works. How can I find a certain dictionary in a list, WITHOUT knowing the definition of that dictionary variabele. (So I can't know that `'x'` references `{'xx': '192.111.1.11'}`).

Comment: That does not look like json. Do you mean if the key `"x"` exists?

Comment: I didn't tab it correctly in this question of course.

Comment: @ThomasW: no, the sample text you gave is not valid JSON. Valid JSON would use double quotes.

Comment: Yes in my python file i've got that, I just typed it over incorrectly!

Comment: @ThomasW: never type what you can copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a the presence of a *key* in one of the dictionaries; use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression to test each dictionary in turn:

```
if any(x in d for d in somelist):
```

This will stop testing dictionaries as soon as a match is confirmed.

I've presumed that you already loaded the JSON into a Python structure.

Demo:

```
>>> somelist = [{'x':{'xx':'192.111.1.11'}},{'y':{'yx':'192.111.1.12'}}]
>>> any('x' in d for d in somelist)
True
>>> any('z' in d for d in somelist)
False
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Will check as answer when possible :)

Comment: By any chance do you know how to find the index for example 'x' in a list without knowing its reference?

Comment: @ThomasW: you can use `next(i for i, d in enumerate(somelist) if x in d)` to get the index of the first matching dictionary.

Comment: @ThomasW: or just use `next(d for d in somelist if x in d)` to get the first match directly.